# How to stop code overwriting cells with values in them

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to tweak the following code which enters today's date in column B when you change column A.  I'd only like this code to run when column B is empty as I'm experiencing an issue where worksheet_change is too broad and past dates entered are getting overwritten when new changes are made inadvertently.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).Value = Date
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: You test the range to be empty, but that is in col A, why not test col B as well?

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the value is already a date

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
Dim WorkRng As Range
Dim Rng As Range
Dim xOffsetColumn As Integer
Set WorkRng = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), Target)
xOffsetColumn = 1
If Not WorkRng Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For Each Rng In WorkRng
        If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Rng.Value) Then
            With Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn)
                If Not VBA.Information.IsDate(.Value) Then
                    .Value = Date
                    .NumberFormat = "mm-dd-yyyy"
                End If
            End With
        Else
            Rng.Offset(0, xOffsetColumn).ClearContents
        End If
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End If

End Sub
```